# Is the analyzer really trustworthy concerning the detection of memory leaks?

Tags: ios, memory-leaks

In my app delegate I have the following code snippet:

```
...

@synthesize model = _model;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    ...

    // Allocate the model
    self.model = [[Model alloc] init];

    ...
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_model release];
    [super dealloc];
}

...
```

The XCode Analyzer reports a potential memory leak on the line *after* the allocation of the model (it did go away when I added an `autorelease` statement, so I guess it just got mixed up with the line numbers). Is this truly a memory leak or is the analyzer confused? After all a release is done in the dealloc method. So is there a potential of a memory leak here and in which situations?

If that's so I guess the solution would be to add `autorelase` to the allocation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a memory leak if the property is defined as `retain` because it has a retain count of 2 - once for `alloc` and once on assignment to the property - but you only release it once.  Xcode does [get confused](http://xcodewtf.tumblr.com/post/9767354276/error-locations-will-be-approximated) about [line numbers though](http://xcodewtf.tumblr.com/post/10176898334/warning-locations-will-be-approximated-too).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is trustworthy!

If you click on the blue arrow icon on the line where the analyzer shows a leak:

[image]

it will give you more information about the leak, showing exactly where it originated, and in this case the reason why it appears on the next line:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The static analyser is very trust worthy. after all ARC is completely based on it. It has to be good in order for iOS5 programming to work.